# List chat messages QuickBlox History Message

Tags: android, quickblox

It is possible to load all history message according to custom parameter.
Currently we set a according to setPageLimit. But i want to use a custom parameter. [image] . Custom parameter is sh_id,sh_r_id,customer_id, date

```
private void loadHistory(String dialogId){
    QBDialog qbDialog = new QBDialog(dialogId);
    QBRequestGetBuilder customObjectRequestBuilder = new QBRequestGetBuilder();
    customObjectRequestBuilder.setPagesLimit(150); 

    QBChatService.getDialogMessages(qbDialog, customObjectRequestBuilder, new QBEntityCallbackImpl<ArrayList<QBChatHistoryMessage>>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(ArrayList<QBChatHistoryMessage> messages, Bundle args) {

            try {
                qbShopAdpt = new QBShopkeeperChatAdapter(mContext, new ArrayList<QBMessage>(),customer_id,sh_r_id1);
                qbchatlv.setAdapter(qbShopAdpt);
                for(QBMessage msg : messages) {
                    if(customer_id.equals(msg.getProperty("customer_id")) && sh_r_id1.equals(msg.getProperty("sh_r_id")) && SessionManager.getSignIn(mContext).getId()==Integer.valueOf(msg.getProperty("sh_id"))){
                        showMessage(msg);
                    }
                }
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                Log.e(Tag, e.toString());
            }catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                Log.e(Tag, e.toString());
            }catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(Tag, e.toString());
            }
            hideProgress();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(List<String> errors) {
            AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
            dialog.setMessage("load chat history errors: " + errors).create().show();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try by this code for save chat may be this i am not shure

```
QBChatMessage chatMessage = new QBChatMessage();
chatMessage.setProperty("save_to_history", "1");
```

get chat by this

```
QBDialog qbDialog = new QBDialog("53cfc593efa3573ebd000017");
QBRequestGetBuilder requestBuilder = new QBRequestGetBuilder();
requestBuilder.setPagesLimit(100);
QBChatService.getDialogMessages(qbDialog, customObjectRequestBuilder, new
QBEntityCallbackImpl<ArrayList<QBChatMessage>>() {
@Override
public void onSuccess(ArrayList<QBChatMessage> messages, Bundle args) {
 }
 @Override
public void onError(List<String> errors) {

}
});
```

Try By this code it may be help you try by this link.
[Here is Link](http://quickblox.com/developers/Android_XMPP_Chat_Sample)

Comment: Ok thanks, but  how to get a data from custom parameter. Because only 100 record are getting for me. It is possible for getting all record with out use of page skips.

Comment: what you want to see is your mean to look all friends list or what ...?

Comment: Sir I means to say in private chat window getting all history record with out use of setPageLimit and setPagesSkip. Only getting all history message using a custom parameter sh_id,sh_r_id and customer_id. If you know. Please help me for getting a history message.

Comment: if u have selected a user and click on that user then at a time of click get user all info in shared prefrence and get in private chat which info need to get history and post chat u can use

Comment: this is not helpful Answer